# Why does `..` in the command line results in `permission denied` error?

Tags: linux, macos, command-line

In the zsh command line, `..` (`dot dot` - with no space, same as the parent directory address in a path) results in a `permission denied` response. How is `..` interpreted? As an unknown command, I should get `command not found`, not an execution error. Also, it is not interpreted as `. .` (`dot space dot`) as that results in a `no such file` error.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Questions about shell usage should be posted to [unix.se], [apple.se], or [su] instead.

Comment: One of the things a shell does to find commands is to search the directories in your `$PATH` for files (programs) by that name, and try to execute them. `..` exists in every unix directory as a link to the parent directory, so in fact `..` *is found* in the first directory in `$PATH`. But you can't execute directories, and trying to will get you a permissions error. Also, concerning `. .` vs `..` -- spaces are *incredibly important* delimiters in shell syntax, and adding or removing them almost always changes the meaning of a command.

Comment: ty @GordonDavisson. Yeah, I was just experimenting to see if it is interpreted as `. .`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `..` refers to the parent directory. If you try to run `..` as a command, you might get a "permission denied" error because you're trying to execute a directory, which doesn't have execution permissions.

It's not a "command not found" error because `..` exists, you're just lacking permission. To get to the parent directory, use `cd ..`. To run a command in the parent directory, use relative paths like `../command`.

Comment: I am familiar with `..` in the path and for navigating. What threw me off was that executing directories will result in "permission denied".

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the shell you use as "command line"!
On my Linux's `bash` `..` is indeed an unknown command. On some shell, `..` could be interpreted as run ".." which could result in permission denied.

You can lookup which shell is used by default on your OS and do a specific search about its syntax!

Comment: It is zsh on mac.